# How do I test models that validate a polymorphic relationship by what interface the related model implements?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

This is all on Laravel 7. I'm using PHPUnit / the built-in testing suite Laravel provides.

I have a `Rating` model (see code below) that has a polymorphic relationship called `content` (as a default name). Upon creation of this model, it accepts `content` only if it implements `RateableInterface` by using `instanceof`.

Now, to test this I am currently using another model called `Entity`. It *does* implement `RateableInterface`, so the test code works. However, I would really like to separate `Entity` from my `RatingTest` because I know that unit tests should be isolated and not depend on outside code. If `Entity` was ever changed to *not* implement `RateableInterface`, that would cause problems for my test, but it really shouldn't since `Entity` doesn't have much to do with `Rating`.

I *would* create a stub of `Entity`, but before checking to see if `content` implements `RateableInterface`, I first check if `content` even exists in the database. On top of that, my goal is to de-couple this test from `Entity`, so it's not really something I want to do.

I also have tried to create a stub of `RateableInterface`, but this also doesn't work for the above reason: it will not exist in the database. Even if the stub could be saved, I don't have a table for this and I don't think creating a migration for it is the right way to move forwards (correct me if I'm wrong here). In addition to this, I have tried making a new class in the test file that implements `RateableInterface`, but again I would have to make a new migration and I don't think that's the right answer.

I have spent a few hours on this and I'm really just not sure how to test this without using a specific implementation of `RateableInterface` like `Entity`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, as you will see below, the interface has `canRate()`, which is another reason why I'd like to move away from `Entity`. A stub would solve this, it being able to define what the method would return, but I've already explained why that isn't working.

Code:

`Rating`

```
<?php

// ...

class Rating
{
    public function content()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    // ...
    
    public function canCreate(): bool
    {
        // Check if content exists in the db.
        if (!$this->content) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if content implements RateableInterface
        if (!$this->content instanceof RateableInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->content->canRate()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

`RateableInterface`

```
<?php

// ...

interface RateableInterface
{
    public function canRate(): bool;
}
```

`Entity`

```
<?php

// ...

class Entity implements RateableInterface
{
    public function ratings(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Rating::class, 'content');
    }

    // ...
    
    public function canRate(): bool
    {
        // Do some work...
        // Check for X and Y...
        return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

`RatingTest`

```
<?php

// ...

class RatingTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testThatCanCreateReturnsTrueOnSuccess()
    {
        // I want to replace this so this test does not rely on Entity.
        $entity = factory(Entity::class)->create();
        $rating = new Rating(
            [
                'content_id' => $entity->id,
                'content_type' => 'Entity', // This is resolved
            ]
        }

        self::assertTrue($rating->canCreate());
    }
}
```